# Mod Rewrite for Server Status 503, depending upon URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect only if there is an error (server status 503). Without the error, this is the redirect script, which works fine:

```
Redirect /abc https://www.abc.com/pqr.html
Redirect /cde https://www.cde.com/pqr.html
```

But, this redirects /abc to https:// www.abc.com/pqr.html in all cases. I want this redirect only in case of an error. This syntax:

```
ErrorDocument 503 https://www.abc.com/pqr.html
```

redirects all urls with 503 error message to https:// www.abc.com/pqr.html. But, I want the /cde ones with 503 error messages to be redirected to https:// www.cde.com/pqr.html

Any clues on how to do it?

Comment: @alexn, cde is not a physical folder. Its part of the URL, like google.co.in/music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perfectly works for me. Got this answer in Apache Forums:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
   ServerName www.mysite.com
   <Location /books>
           ErrorDocument 503 http://www.mypartnersite.com/books
   </Location>
   <Location /music>
           ErrorDocument 503 http://www.mypartnersite.com/music
   </Location>
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```